# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException While calling an Rest API from Spring boot Application

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

Hi I am running two Spring boot Applications. From one Application I am trying to access Rest API of another application using RestTemplate.

This is my API present in first Spring boot which I am trying to call from my second Spring boot Application.

```
MovieControllerData.java

 package com.movies.pinku;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


        @RestController
        @RequestMapping("/movies")
        public class MovieControllerData {

        @RequestMapping("/{movieId}")
        public Movie getMovieData(@PathVariable("movieId") String movieId) {


            return new Movie("1223", "test123");

        }

    }

    Movie.java

    package com.example.MicroServices.MicroServicesSpringBoot;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class Movie {

        private String movieId;

        public Movie(String movieId, String name) {
            super();
            this.movieId = movieId;
            this.name = name;
        }

        private String name;

        public String getMovieId() {
            return movieId;
        }

        public void setMovieId(String movieId) {
            this.movieId = movieId;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

    }


    This is another class in second Spring boot application where I am trying to call first Rest API

    package com.example.MicroServices.MicroServicesSpringBoot;

    import java.util.Collections;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;


    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/catalog")
    public class MovieController {

        @RequestMapping("/{userId}")
        public List<CatalogItem> getCataLog(@PathVariable("userId") String userId){

            final String uri = "http://localhost:8083/movies/{movieId}";

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("movieId", "foo");

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            Movie movie = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, Movie.class , params);
            System.out.println("Data in movie is=============:"+ movie);
            return Collections.singletonList(new CatalogItem(movie.getName(), "Action", movie.getMovieId()));

        }

    }
```

I am getting this error

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.MicroServices.MicroServicesSpringBoot.Movie` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67) ~[jackson-databind-2.10.0.jar:2.10.0]

Comment: With the default object mapper configuration, usually, you need a no args constructor for the deserialisation to work. It seems that it could be the problem with the class ```Movie```

Comment: @D Lawren Ya thats correct.  Default constructor was not there thats y i was getting that error. Thanks.